# How to sort a recyclerview based on one list and not the other?

Tags: java, android, list, sorting, android-recyclerview

I am fairly new to Android Development and I have been stuck at this for some time. I've tried searching but nothing that really answers my question.

Scenario:
I have a Recycler view w/ an Adapter & viewholder (the usual)
My Adapter takes 2 lists. 
exampleListA & exampleListB.

exampleListA is a Fruit object & exampleListB is a Pricing Object

These lists are coming back from a network call, where Fruit objects are coming in first.

My problem:I need to sort the list by the Pricing object, from least to highest. I tried Collections.sort(exampleListB ...) , the list gets sorted (I did a log) but it seems the recyclerview will always make exampleListA take importance over the other.

What is the best way, maybe even simplest (though I am not afraid to do some work) to sort exampleListA in order of a property in exampleListB ??

Anything would help, thanks!

```
public class GroceriesAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<GroceriesAdapter.Viewholder>{
///.... generic stuff
public GrocereisAdapter(ArrayList<Fruit> fruitList, ArrayList<Pricing> pricingList){
this.fruitList = fruitList;
this.pricingList = pricingList;


void onBindViewHolder(Viewholder holder, int position){
Fruit fruit = fruitList.get(position);
Pricing price = pricingList.get(position);
holder.fruitTitle.setText(fruit.getName);
holder.pricingPrice.setText(price.getPrice);




public class MainActivity ....
//General OnCreate & variables...
ArrayList<Fruit> fruitList = new ArrayList();
ArrayList<Pricing> priceList = new ArrayList();
public void loadData(){
//Does Rest Call..
fruitList.addAll(restResponse.getFruitObjects);
priceList.addAll(restResponse.getPriceObjects);
```

now originally I thought this would work.. but it isn't. But just so you know what I Tried;

```
//After rest call, before adding them to lists.
Collections.sort(priceList, new Comparator<Pricing>) {
//general code that comes up when calling this..
return Double.compare(price.getPrice, p1.getPrice);
```

Thats pretty much it, nothing too too fancy. just taking properties from one list and the other and creating my views.  *(Note edited for the project I'm working on)

Comment: it seams as if the lists are related but sorting one list doesn't mean that automatically the other list is sorted --> You should find a solution to link those two lists

Comment: can you post your adapter code ?

Comment: see my updates @Abhishekkumar , my viewholder is standard too. Stating the textviews & setting Id's

Comment: Try by implementing a Comparator interface on your Fruit class, so you can sort by pricing. Check this tutorial https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/comparator-interface-java/

Comment: So you're saying... from that example.. in my fruit model class..


class sortByPricing implements Comparator<Pricing> {
Override
public int compare (Pricing price, Pricing p1){
return Double.compare(price.getPrice, p1.getPrice);

Something like that? then call it in my main activity???
@Xaren

Comment: Hello, @user9306760 Are you solved this ? Can you post your json response so that i can understand, make a logic to do that